# Is there a list of which numbers represent which characters when using msvcrt?

Tags: python, msvcrt

I'm sure there are several out there but I'm not sure if I'm wording it correctly so I can't find any.  In case I have worded it wrong this is what I mean:

```
while 1:
    char = msvcrt.getch()
    if char == chr(27):
        break
```

This tests for a specific key press (esc if I'm not mistaken), but say I wanted to test for space bar instead, what number would that be?  Or, ideally, is there a list for me to refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I understand your situation. It's really annoying when this happens. There are several approaches. One of them, which is my favourite, is to create a very tiny program with 4 lines of code that tells you the number of any key. All what you have to do is create a new program and paste the following in:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
   key = msvcrt.getch()
   key = ord(key)
   print(key)
```

What this does is it waits for you to press any key and then prints out the number of it. If you wanted a list on the internet or something im afraid i couldn't find anything, however this will work.

Also, make sure you save this code on your desktop and run it by double clicking on it. Espescially if you have windows( don't know why but it doesn't work on the interpreter.) I hope it helps! Please comment for any problems below.